# Eclipse PDT (helios) autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-3.6

I've just completed a new eclipse helios install and I am wondering why the autocompletion is not working properly; in my older versions (ganymede/galileo) it was.

It's working for simple functions and class-methods but:

- It doesn't know methods which have been inherited from other classes
- It won't show autocompletion for chained methods which return `$this`.

For instance:

```
class y
{
    protected $_a;

    public function setA($a)
    {
        $this->_a = $a;
        return $this;
    }
}

class x extends y
{
    protected $_b;

    public function setB($b)
    {
        $this->_b = $b;
        return $this;
    }
}

$x = new x;
$x->[AUTOCOMPLETION]
```

Here `[AUTOCOMPLETION]` only shows the methods directly implemented in `x`, but not the methods of `y`.

When I do:

```
$x->setB(123)
  ->[AUTOCOMPLETION]
```

...the autocompletion doesn't work at all. Both of these cases worked great in my previous versions. So what's wrong? Did I mis-configure something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the version I was using was bugged. Eclipse 3.7.2 works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

work ok on Mac. it shows both setA and setB

Post a bug report in bugzilla

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT